# Initialization of data member in initialization section using this pointer

Tags: c++, initialization

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Child {
    size_t age;
    string nation;

    public:
        Child() : age(0), nation("N/A") { }
        Child(size_t a, string nation) : age((a <= 5) ? a : 0), (this->nation)(nation) { }
        void showDet() {cout << age << endl << nation;}

};
```

In the 2nd constructor I am using this pointer to initialize string type member var nation but getting error "name of member or class is missing"

Comment: `this` is unavailable outside expressions in a constructor initializer list. Use `nation(nation)`, this is a valid construction.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: In addition consider to have different names for members and ctor parameters. IMHO it is clearer that way.

Comment: How? I read books. See **Explanation** there https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: logically `this->nation` implies object is constructed and you're trying to access it but its a wrong assumption hence its invalid.

Comment: @madhur4127 It's not true. `this` can be used there in expressions, see the link I posted: `j{this->i}`

Comment: @273K doesn't my point stands? `this->i` has been constructed before its used but same cannot be said for `this->nation`.

Comment: my bad sorry, I meant to say member is constructed and not object.

Comment: there are no childs that are 6 years old? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Long story short**: C++ standard doesn't allow `this` keyword to be used in this context.

---

`this` has well defined set of scopes it can appear in ([[expr.prim.this]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.this#:this)):

- Scope of a (non-static) member function:

```cpp
class S {
    int i;

    void foo() {
        this->i = 4;
    }
};
```

- (Non-static) default member initialiser

```cpp
class S {
    int i = sizeof(*this);
};
```

For any other context use of `this` is considered ill-formed by the standard. One can argue, that member initialiser list falls into a member function's scope category, however identifiers in this list have special name lookup rules ([[class.base.init]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#2)):

> Lookup for an unqualified name in a mem-initializer-id ignores the constructor's function parameter scope.
>
> Unless the [mem-initializer-id](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#nt:mem-initializer-id) names the constructor's class, a non-static data member of the constructor's class, or a direct or virtual base of that class, the [mem-initializer](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#nt:mem-initializer) is ill-formed.

At the same time it means, that you can safely initialise member variables with constructor parameters of the same name:

```cpp
class S {
    int i;

    S(int i): i(i) {}
};
```

Last, but not least, the semantic you want to use is still valid in the body of a constructor, because it's where member function scope comes into play:

```cpp
class S {
    int i;

    S(int i) {
        this->i = i;
    }
};
```